# Revert Ubuntu 14.04 to default python after uninstalling anaconda

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda

I am new to ubuntu and the whole linux environment. I installed Anaconda on my system, but I would like to use the default python now for some reason. I removed the anaconda directory , but now the system can't find the python installation (obviously, but I dont know how to get to the right one). 
Can someone write out a step-by-step as to how I revert back to the original python (the default one ubuntu 14.04 comes with) ?

Thank you

Answer (score 10):

In your `.bashrc` file you will have a line something like, Anaconda adds it during the installation process:

```
export PATH=$HOME/anaconda/bin:$PATH
```

You need to remove that line, do a `source .bashrc` and type python, that should open a shell using your system default python.

Comment: There is no such line in my .bashrc but still when I run python from terminal Conda distribution starts.

Comment: You can anyway find some lines related to anaconda, and you could just remove all of them. Then do a `source .bashrc`.